# xmlgraphics: 'Arial Unicode MS' font does not work for Cyrillic

Tags: xml, unicode, fonts, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I want to generate a PDF for Czech language, and I'm having problems with some characters. For example the character "Č".

I'm having "#eská republika". When it should be "Česká republika".

I know that the font Arial Unicode MS font supports these characters. But I can't make it work, even following this recommendation:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xmlgraphics-fop-users/200702.mbox/%3C45CA27AC.30302@usherbrooke.ca%3E

```
    <fo:block color="#000000" font-family="'Arial Unicode MS'" font-size="10.0pt">
                        <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
                            <fo:table-column column-width="130.0pt" />
                            <fo:table-body>
                                <fo:table-row height="12.0pt">
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block>
                                            <xsl:apply-templates select="HEADER/COUNTRY" />
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
```

any idea please?

Comment: It seems strange to me that you need the Arial Unicode font, the "Č" should be displayable with the standard Arial font. Just to be more accurate: Č is not a Cyrillic character, it is a letter of Latin extended 1 in Unicode.

Comment: Maybe the original text isn't read using the correct encoding.

Comment: Do you get any warning during pdf creation (missing glyphs, font substitution, ...)? Have you configured the fonts in the configuration file (see http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/fonts.html#register)?

Comment: A similar question where I tried to write a detailed answer: [Apache FOP Displaying ### with SunSim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895984/apache-fop-displaying-with-sunsim/28251945)

Comment: It looks we don't have Arial font installed in the Linux production environment