# XSL-FO font need Arial, but it's still TimesRoman

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I'm new in xsl editing and neew make some changes in one xsl document.
Whole document is in TimesRoman but i need one block in Arial. Tried different thing but it still remains in TimesRoman.

There is beginning of the document. In the end of sample is block what i need to be in Arial.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:rx="http://www.renderx.com/XSL/Extensions" xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="section1-first-page" page-width="8.268055555555555in" page-height="11.693055555555556in" margin-top="8mm" margin-bottom="9mm" margin-right="0mm" margin-left="10mm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="0mm" margin-bottom="0mm" margin-right="15mm" margin-left="20mm"/>
                    <fo:region-before region-name="first-page-header" extent="11in" margin-right="0mm" margin-left="0mm"/>
                    <fo:region-after region-name="first-page-footer" extent="11in" display-align="after"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="section1-odd-page" page-width="8.268055555555555in" page-height="11.693055555555556in" margin-top="8mm" margin-bottom="9mm" margin-right="15mm" margin-left="30mm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="0mm" margin-bottom="0mm" margin-right="0mm" margin-left="0mm"/>
                    <fo:region-before region-name="odd-page-header" extent="11in"/>
                    <fo:region-after region-name="odd-page-footer" extent="11in" display-align="after"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="section1-even-page" page-width="8.268055555555555in" page-height="11.693055555555556in" margin-top="8mm" margin-bottom="9mm" margin-right="15mm" margin-left="30mm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="0mm" margin-bottom="0mm" margin-right="0mm" margin-left="0mm"/>
                    <fo:region-before region-name="even-page-header" extent="11in"/>
                    <fo:region-after region-name="even-page-footer" extent="11in" display-align="after"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
                <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="section1-page-sequence-master">
                    <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="section1-first-page"/>
                    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference odd-or-even="odd" master-reference="section1-odd-page"/>
                        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference odd-or-even="even" master-reference="section1-even-page"/>
                    </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                </fo:page-sequence-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="section1-page-sequence-master" format="1" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
                <fo:static-content flow-name="first-page-header" font-size="7pt" text-align="right" font-family="Arial">
                    <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="first-page-header" retrieve-position="first-including-carryover" retrieve-boundary="page"/>
                    <fo:block>
                        <fo:table>
                            <fo:table-column column-number="1"  column-width="115mm" />
                            <fo:table-column column-number="1"  column-width="65mm"  />
                            <fo:table-body>
                                <fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block font-family="Arial" color="#000000" font-size="6pt" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt" text-align="left" xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags">
                                            <fo:inline font-size="6pt">
                                                <xsl:variable name="logo_url" select="/DOKUMENT/LOGO_URL"/>
                                                <fo:external-graphic content-width="40%" content-height="40%" src="url(&quot;{$logo_url}&quot;)"/>
                                            </fo:inline>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block font-family="Arial" color="#000000" font-size="6pt" space-before="5pt" space-after="5pt" text-align="left" xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags">
                                            <fo:inline font-size="8pt">
                                                <fo:block/>
                                            </fo:inline>
                                            <fo:inline font-weight="bold" font-size="7pt">
                                                <fo:leader leader-length="0pt"/>ASUTUSESISESEKS KASUTAMISEKS</fo:inline>
```

Comment: What is you rendering engine for the XSL-FO? fop? Can you provide us with a fully runnable example (XML + XSLT). Thanks.

Comment: If you are using FOP, it could be a **font configuration** issue; if that's the case, here is a [relevant question + answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895984/apache-fop-displaying-with-sunsim) (the question talks about a chinese font, but the configuration steps are the same)