# Using OTF font format in XSL FO to generate PDF

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using Apache FO in Java to generate PDF from XML. I have used TTF file format font in my code. But now I have to use OTF format.

I referred many URL's to get info how to create datamatrix for a OTF font. But could not find any.

Could someone tell me how to integrate OTF type format in XSL FO to generate PDF.
[Attaching the font documentation provided by apache](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/fonts.html).

Comment: What FOP Version are you using? Have you tried simply adding the OTF fonts to the config? Are you generating some more special pdf like PDF/Axxx?

Comment: No there's nothing special about the PDF. It's just a .pdf extension.
I am using version 2.0 for FOP

Comment: I haven't tried adding OTF font as it is into the fop.config file. The way by which I think we can do that is by creating the font datamatrix and placing the XML file into the fop.xconf file

Comment: right now I am referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379281/xsl-fo-how-to-add-helvetica-neue-fonts-and-output-to-pdf)

Comment: Font metrics (the XML files you are talking about) are **no more needed** in recent versions of FOP; the question you linked refers to an older version. You just have to configure the font in `fop.xconf`.

Comment: @lfurini could you point at some URL which could help me to configure OTF font in fop.xconf file

Comment: Hello all I think I was wrong about the fop version. I opened the fop.xconf file which showed me <fop version="1.0"> which means we are using an older version for fop.

Comment: That version only refers to the configuration file format, it is *not* the version of FOP. If you don't know which FOP version you are using, type `fop -version` in a prompt from FOP's folder, latest FOP version is 2.2. OTF fonts can be configured just like "normal" TTF fonts, you can see [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28251945/4453460) for more details.