# xsl:fo SVG reference

Tags: xml, xslt, svg, xsl-fo

I am searching for a guide(reference) to use svg in xsl:fo because i want to draw checkboxes. I don't know which attributes I can use.

I am using xslt 2.0 and oxygen.

My xsl:fo code now for the checkbox:

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object> 
    <svg:svg width="5" height="5" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <svg:rect width="5" height="5"  style="stroke-width:5;  stroke:rgb(250,0,0)"/>
        <svg:line/>
    </svg:svg> 
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

Comment: Providing external references is off-topic. You need to ask a specific answerable question. What exactly is your problem, what's happening instead?

Comment: With this code I get a black rectangle but I need to know which attributes can I use in style? are they the same to css?

Comment: You should get a black rectangle with a red edge. fill : blue; should make it blue.

Comment: thank you  now I have an solution
here an link about a good tool: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_rect4

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your requirements are, but you might just need a ballot character, like the following (or `&#x2611;` in XML):

## ☑

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_mark for alternatives.

Comment: how can i use these "&#x2611;" if I use these in an fo:block i get an # ?

Comment: You must use a font that has a glyph for that code point; if you are using Apache FOP you also need to [configure the font](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25895984/4453460).