# FOP PDF Generation

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xslt, apache-fop

I have a requirement to generate a PDF Using FOP. I can generate the PDF using FOP. But the problem is, i have to set our custom fonts in FOP PDF Generation.When i explored on internet, They have given a steps which i followed in below links

[Adding Fonts in FOP](http://blog.imaginea.com/registering-custom-fonts-for-apache-fop/)

When i tried above steps, am getting an error message "ClassNotFoundException". I tried with replacing the jars and still am getting same error message.Can anyone help on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache FOP Displaying ### with SunSim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895984/apache-fop-displaying-with-sunsim)

Comment: The tutorial you found is quite dated and refers to an older version of FOP which required the generation of metrics files. FOP's most recent versions don't need that any more (and the class producing the metrics file has probably been removed). If you are using a recent version of FOP (2.0 has been released this year), my answer to the question I linked could help you.