# fop pdf generation with font awesome icon

Tags: java, pdf-generation, apache-fop

Please help me out,
I have two doubts in fop pdf generation

1. How to include font-awesome icons or utf characters in FOP based pdf generation
2. apply color based on the value.

Please help me

Any suggestions are accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) just like any other font:

1. in the FO file, set the `font-family` property on the `fo:block` (or `fo:inline`, ...) containing the [Unicode entities for the icons](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet) you need
2. create/edit a FOP configuration file to map the `font-family` value to the TrueType font file contained in the Font Awesome distribution
3. tell FOP to use your configuration file

As for the **color**, you can use the properties `color` and `background-color` to set the glyphs font color and background color.

An example, tested with FOP 2.0:

**FO fragment**

```
<fo:block>
    Icons:
    <fo:inline font-family="FontAwesome">
        &#xf13d; &#xf242; &#xf02d; &#xf27b;
    </fo:inline>
</fo:block>
<fo:block>
    Coloured icons:
    <fo:inline font-family="FontAwesome" color="#AA0000">
        &#xf13d; &#xf242; &#xf02d; &#xf27b;
    </fo:inline>
</fo:block>
<fo:block>
    Coloured icons with background:
    <fo:inline font-family="FontAwesome" color="#FFFFFF" background-color="#AA0000">
        &#xf13d; &#xf242; &#xf02d; &#xf27b;
    </fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

**FOP configuration fragment:**

```
<renderer mime="application/pdf">
  ...
  <fonts>
    <font embed-url="/Users/furini/font-awesome-4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf">
      <font-triplet name="FontAwesome" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
    </font>
    ...
  </fonts>
  ...
</renderer>
```

**Output:**

[image: PDF output screenshot]

Note that you get a warning, but it's nothing to worry about (it just tells you that Font Awesome does not have a glyph for the default hyphenation character, but you are not going to use hyphenation with icons anyway!):

```
25-ott-2015 13.31.38 org.apache.fop.fo.properties.CommonHyphenation getHyphChar
WARNING: Substituted specified hyphenation character (0x2d) with 0x20 because the font doesn't have the specified hyphenation character: FontAwesome,normal,400
```

([this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28251945/4453460) gives some more details about font configuration and the errors/warnings you could get)

*(disclosure: I'm a FOP developer, though not very active nowadays)*