# Apache FOP using Chinese bold fonts

Tags: java, apache-fop, chinese-locale

Has anybody been using chinese bold fonts successfully in PDFs generated using Apache FOP?

I tried the Windows-supplied font mingliub.ttc, "MingLiU-ExtB", but it won't render (displays ###). The normal font mingliu.ttc, "MingLiU" works perfectly, but only for non-bold text.

I configured both font-collections exactly the same way with the proper subfont-name: mingliu.ttc with sub-font: MingLiU vs. mingliub.ttc with sub-font: MingLiU-ExtB

The font for normal characters (mingliu.ttc) works, the font for bold characters (mingliub.ttc) doesn't.

Related question (but only for normal fonts): [Apache FOP Displaying ### with SunSim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895984/apache-fop-displaying-with-sunsim/28251945?noredirect=1#comment63728289_28251945)