# Creating special characters table for FOP template

Tags: xml, utf-8, pdf-generation, special-characters, apache-fop

I'm trying to create a db table with all special character and foreign languages symbole and fonts with their HTML code to for preventing xml error while converting them through FOP process into pdf(s).

Would anyone suggest a better way?

Or help me get resources to add special characters into the table?

Comment: What do you mean with *special characters*? Could you include a (small) FO example demonstrating your problem?

Comment: i meant UTF-8 character code list

Comment: Then I think it's just a matter of [using and configuring](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28251945/4453460) a font having the characters you want to use.

Comment: seems like i figured out the solution. So, what i did was start progress (openEdge/4gl) with itf-8 unicode page intead and then ran the query. Works fine :)

Comment: Also, had to do a bit to convert Excel file with Utf8Code to cvs for upload. Here the solution, was to first convert the file into notepad and save as Unicode .txt extenstion. Then opn the notepad file, and replace tab space with "," and then save into cvs format.