# Issue with Apache FOP 1.1 <auto-detect/> on CentOS

Tags: java, apache, apache-fop

I have an issue with Cyrillic font in Apache FOP 1.1 on CentOS: ######## is shown instead of symbols.

This is fragment from fop.xconf:

```
<fonts>              
    <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="bold"/>       
    <auto-detect/>
 </fonts>
```

On Windows 10 it works fine, on CentOS it produces ######.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Related, though not exactly the same siituation, as you are already configuring the fonts: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25895984/4453460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `font-triplet` element should be inside a `font` element pointing to the font file, for example:

```
<font kerning="yes" embed-url="/usr/share/fonts/Arial.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
    <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
</font>
```

Moreover, it seems like FOP cannot find a font folder in the "usual" positions; you can try explicitly adding a font folder

```
<directory>/usr/share/fonts/</directory>
```

The specific error message(s) you get could help pinpointing the specific problem.

Comment: Must be <directory>/usr/share/fonts/</directory> inside <fonts> </fonts> ?

Comment: Yes; you can have a look at [FOP's site](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/fonts.html#bulk) for further examples and details.