# XSLT - XSL-FO to PDF with Japanese characters not working? Appending '####' into result PDF

Tags: java, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am converting XSL-FO to PDF using FOP with Japanese character, but it's inserting #### into result pdf. 
But the same code is working fine for english characters.

[source.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfkDQ.png)

[style.xsl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abbG9.png)

**java code** where i am converting XSL-FO to PDF

transformer.transform(xml,result);

Comment: Did you set the encoding properly?

Comment: set encoding to UTF-8

Comment: Thanks vikram - but where should i set UTF-8?

Comment: @Litelite - where should i set encoding?

Comment: Which XSL-FO formatter are you using?

Comment: Apach FOP  formatter i am using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache FOP Displaying ### with SunSim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895984/apache-fop-displaying-with-sunsim)

Comment: In your `.xsl` stylesheet on line 3, change to: `<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" standalone="no" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>`

Comment: Hee steven- i tried with your solution, it's not working.