# How to configure kannada font in Xsl-FO PDF and Java

Tags: java, spring, xsl-fo

I want to add kannada font in Xsl-FO PDF. I was searching and found out that i have to download TrueType(.ttf) file to add new fonts and configure it. Can anyone guide me to the complete configuration procedure to add kannada font.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which XSL-FO formatter are you using?

Comment: If you are using FOP, you can find directions in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28251945/4453460).

Comment: I configured but i'm facing problem to display can anyone please help me find more information in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632198/xsl-fop-kannada-font-not-appearing-properly