# XSL FOP Kannada font not appearing properly

Tags: java, spring, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have configured TrueType file in configuration file like this

```
<fop version="1.0">
<renderers>
    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
        <fonts>
            <font embed-url="Nudi_05_k.ttf" kerning="yes">
                <font-triplet name="kannada" style="normal"
                    weight="normal" />
            </font>
            <!-- <font embed-url="Nudi_05_k.ttf" kerning="yes" sub-font="kannada"> 
                <font-triplet name="kannada" style="normal" weight="normal" /> </font> -->
        </fonts>
    </renderer>
</renderers>
```

It has to be displayed in the format as
ಪ.ಪೂ.ಶಿ/ಪ್ರ.ಅ/99-2000/13.3.2000

But it is displaying as
ಪೂಪಿಶ/್ಪರ.ಾದಖಾಲಿತ/2000-01/6-2-2001

Comment: See https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/complexscripts.html

Comment: Could be the same problem as this other question: [Indic font support in Apache FOP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54399302/4453460).