# Indic font support in Apache FOP

Tags: java, truetype, apache-fop

While using Apache FOP 2.2 from my Java application to print Hindi strings in PDF by using mangal.ttf, some Hindi characters are not displayed correctly.
I am Using JDK 1.8 and spring MVC.

I tried lohit.ttf, devanagari.ttf, aparajita.ttf and kokila.ttf but all have the same issue.

### case 1:

When fop-conf.xml is set as below:

```
<font kerning="yes"    embed-url="classpath:/mangal.ttf"   >
<font-triplet name="Mangal" style="normal" weight="normal"></font-triplet>
</font>
```

Result: से is shown like this स े, as shown in this screenshot

[image: case1]

### case 2:

When fop-conf.xml is set as below:

```
<font kerning="yes"   metrics-url="classpath:/mangal.xml" embed-url="classpath:/mangal.ttf"   >
<font-triplet name="Mangal" style="normal" weight="normal"></font-triplet>
</font>
```

Result: problem listed in case 1 is resolved but I am facing another issue attached as shown in the following screenshot

[image: case2]

---

You can see the expected output at the link https://www.fonts.com/font/microsoft-corporation/aparajita) using this sample text:

```
से and ग्रामीण should be printed in pdf
```

Other things I tried:

- I tried [PDFOne](https://www.gnostice.com/PDFOne_Java.asp) to generate the PDF. Yet the same issue. Windows however seems to show it correctly.
- configuring complex-script: `<fop version="1.0"> <complex-scripts disabled="true"/> ... </fop>`
- using the `script` attribute: `<fo:block font-family="ARIALUNI" script="dev2" > देवी ग्रामीण</fo:block>`

**Is there any configuration setting in FOP that I am missing?**

Comment: please refer https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/complexscripts.html

Answer (score 0):

### Shorter, general answer:

If the font is configured but the output is not correct, the problem could be FOP incorrectly determining which **script mode** to use.

**Solution:** explicitly set the [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xsl11-20061205/#script) property in the FO file, using either a [standard](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.3/complexscripts.html#standard_script_codes) or an [extended](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.3/complexscripts.html#extended_script_codes) script code.
Note that **Indic scripts have both a standard code and an extended one** (for example `deva` and `dev2` for Devanagari) and the resulting output is different, so you may need to try them both and choose the appropriate one.

### Longer answer:

I don't have the fonts you mention available, so I tested using the [Amiko](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Amiko) Google Open Font.
More importantly, I know nothing about devanagari script, so I really cannot say whether the output is *right* or *wrong*, I can only compare it with your images.

This is the complete **input file** I used, with the sentence copied from your question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm">
      <fo:region-body/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
      <fo:block font-family="Amiko" script="deva">deva: से and ग्रामीण should be printed in pdf</fo:block>
      <fo:block font-family="Amiko" script="dev2">dev2: से and ग्रामीण should be printed in pdf</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Here is a minimal **configuration**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fop version="1.0">
  <renderers>
    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
      <fonts>
        <font kerning="yes" embed-url="Amiko/Amiko-Regular.ttf">
          <font-triplet name="Amiko" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
        </font>
      </fonts>
    </renderer>
  </renderers>
</fop>
```

which produces this **output**:

[image: output with complex script ON]

If I understand correctly, the output you are trying to achieve is the one with `script="deva"`.

---

Note that the `metrics-url` attribute in your configuration is not needed.

Moreover, putting `<complex-scripts disabled="true"/>` in your configuration has the effect of *disabling* the "complex script" support, so I expect this to produce the *wrong* output.

This **configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fop version="1.0">
  <complex-scripts disabled="true"/>
  <renderers>
    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
      <fonts>
        <font kerning="yes" embed-url="Amiko/Amiko-Regular.ttf">
          <font-triplet name="Amiko" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
        </font>
      </fonts>
    </renderer>
  </renderers>
</fop>
```

produces the following **output**:

[image]

Comment: Hi lfurini,
Thank you so much  Amiko-Regular.ttf is working for me 
Can you explain why mangal.ttf and ARIALUNI.ttf is not working properly (windows 7 is using those ttf files only)
And can you please suggest for gujarati and bengali ttf files

Comment: I don't know while other fonts behave differently: maybe they don't implement some advanced font feature, or maybe FOP does not handle them properly.

Comment: Google Fonts apparently has many available fonts for [Devanagari](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=devanagari), [Gujarati](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=gujarati) and [Bengali](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=bengali) script; I don't know those languages and I never used those fonts, so I don't know whether FOP's output will be correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

This might help others who are struggling to get Indic language support in Apache FOP. I tried to render Hindi with Amiko font and it works like a charm.

I wanted to see if other Indian languages are supported in the same way, after a bit of struggle I could see Kannada can also be rendered .

> ```
>  <font kerning="yes" embed-url="Benne-Regular.ttf"> 
>       <font-triplet name="Benne" style="normal" weight="normal"/> 
>  </font>
> ```

But its mandatory to mention the script in the XSL .

> <fo:block font-family="Benne" script="knda" font-size="16pt"> ಕನ್ನಡ
> ನನಗೆ ಇನ್ನೂ ಒಂದು ಪ್ರಶ್ನೆ ಇದೆ.</fo:block>