# Glyph not shown in PDF

Tags: apache-fop

In the creation of PDF document based on information of a specific system, using fop, i cannot show special characters, showing '#' instead of the character and giving me this WARNS when i create the pdf.

```
12:49:18,637 WARN  [org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent] (default task-3) Glyph "?" (0x11f, gbreve) not available in font "Helvetica".
12:49:18,640 WARN  [org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent] (default task-3) Glyph "?" (0x15e, Scedilla) not available in font "Helvetica".
12:49:19,041 INFO  [org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent] (default task-3) Rendered page #1.
12:49:19,203 WARN  [org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent] (default task-3) Glyph "?" (0x11f, gbreve) not available in font "Helvetica-Bold".
12:49:19,206 WARN  [org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent] (default task-3) Glyph "?" (0x15e, Scedilla) not available in font "Helvetica-Bold".
```

I already changed font family in .xsl but no progress, now it sits like that, i think this uses fop.xconf, which has all the fonts and types.

```
 <!-- Helvetica -->
        <font>
          <afp-font name="Helvetica" type="raster" codepage="T1V10500" encoding="Cp500">
....
</font>
```

and .xsl:

```
<fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" left="25mm" top="42mm" width="160mm" height="100mm"
                                        background-color="rgb(178,178,178)">
                        <fo:block color="white" font-size="29pt">
                            <fo:inline font-weight="bold">PDF</fo:inline> Report <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block color="white" font-size="16pt" margin-top="3mm">
                            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                        </fo:block>
                        <fo:block color="white" font-size="16pt">
                            <xsl:value-of select="address"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:block-container>
```

what can i do more? this is new to me, and already saw some similar threads in Stackoverflow, but none of them really helped.

EDIT: Quick update, maybe the xconf is not used at all? because i already removed all from there and there's no change, cause i am trying to add FreeSerif but none happened..

Comment: Are you telling FOP to use your xconf file (either with the `-c file.xconf` from the command line, or within your java code)?

Comment: An old answer of mine about [font configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28251945/4453460) could come in handy.

Comment: Do i need to create the /conf/ folder and place xconf file there? because i don't have it..  and my fopFactory doesn't have setUserConfig method to place the path to the fop.xconf file.. i am very lost here.. please help me

Comment: You can have the xconf file whereever you prefer, and use the appropriate path when referring to its location. In order to reach a solution incrementally, I would suggest to call fop from the command line to check if the configuration is ok, and then set it in in your code.

Comment: i am debugging the application, so i can see that the uri in FopFactory.newInstance(uri) is pointing to where my fop.xconf file is.. shouldn't it be enough? Onde thing that i saw debugging is the  "fop.foUserAgent = Cannot find local variable 'fop'"  i don't know.. i am really lost here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i figure it out.
It was my fop.xconf file that was being ignored, i mean, i was with the default values when creating the pdf. So to fix it just edited the following files:

**fop.xconf**

```
...
<fonts>
<auto-detect/>
</fonts>
...
```

**file.xsl**

```
<fo:root font-family="Arial">
    <!-- rest of document -->
</fo:root
```

**FopFactoryWithUserAgentAndTransformerFactoryService.java**

```
//get the fop.xconf file to be read by the app
  final URL uri = getClass()
            .getClassLoader()
            .getResource("/pdf/fopfactorybasedir/fop.xconf");
   try{
        if(uri != null){
            fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(uri.getFile()));
            foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
            transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        }
    }catch (SAXException | IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With this i got the xconf file injected! so remember, always check if the xconf file is being read by the app!

Answer (score 1):

lfurini, i saw your  old answer and i'am stuck an step 2, because i don't have that 'conf' dir.
I'am using it on a Java program, i got it in src/main/resources/pdf/fopfactorybasedir inside that dir i have one folder to display the images on my pdf and fop.xconf file ( that  i can't find anywhere in the code.. so that's why i am saying that is not used at all.. ) here's my code..

FopFactoryWithUserAgentAndTransformerFactoryService

```
@ApplicationScoped
        public class FopFactoryWithUserAgentAndTransformerFactoryService {
            private static final Logger LOG = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(FopFactoryWithUserAgentAndTransformerFactoryService.class);
            private static final String ROOT_PATH = "/pdf/fopfactorybasedir/";
            private final FopFactory fopFactory;
            private final FOUserAgent foUserAgent;
            private final TransformerFactory transformerFactory;

            public FopFactoryWithUserAgentAndTransformerFactoryService() throws URISyntaxException {
                final URI uri = FopFactoryWithUserAgentAndTransformerFactoryService.class.getResource(ROOT_PATH).toURI();
                LOG.info("fopBaseUri={}", uri);
                fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(uri);
                foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
                transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            }

            public FopFactory getFopFactory() {
                return fopFactory;
            }
        public Fop newFop(final String outputFormat, final OutputStream out) throws FOPException {
                return fopFactory.newFop(outputFormat, foUserAgent, out);
            }
            ...
```

PDFFactory:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class PdfFactory {

@Inject
private FopFactoryWithUserAgentAndTransformerFactoryService fopFactoryEtAl;

public PdfFactory() {

}

public PdfFactory(final FopFactoryWithUserAgentAndTransformerFactoryService fopFactoryEtAl) {
    this.fopFactoryEtAl = fopFactoryEtAl;
}
public ByteArrayDto generatePdfFromModelObject(final Object model, final String xslFileName)
....
```

The question is, how can i use my fop.xconf file? maybe if i use it, the   will be enough... ?