# Hebrew Characters are displayed as junk values

Tags: pdf-generation, apache-fop

I am using Apache fop for PDF generation, using the belwp jars

1) Baitik all 
2) fop
3) xmlgraphics-commons
4) avalon-framework
5) pdfbox
6) Fontbox

Can anybody help me on these.

Comment: Please share more details, e.g. your code and the versions of these libraries.

Comment: This is probably a [font configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25895984/4453460) issue.