# XSL FO sometimes returns hashtag instead of wanted unicode character

Tags: xslt, unicode, xsl-fo

I have a simple xsl fo block:

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:inline>&#9651;</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

I want to output triangle symbol △ but it only returns #. I have the same problem with medium box ◼. I tried changing font. What else could be the problem?

Comment: You need a font that has glyphs for the triangle and box characters. Do you use Apache FOP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache FOP Displaying ### ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25895984/4453460) (_if_ you are using FOP).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configure FOP to load the system fonts:

```
<renderers>
  <renderer mime="application/pdf">
     <fonts>
        <!-- automatically detect operating system installed fonts -->
        <auto-detect/>
     </fonts>
  </renderer>
</renderers>
```

https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/fonts.html#awt