# Not Able to render Japanese Language From XML Using XSLT3.0 FOP-2.8

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

In my xml Japanese language is also flowing in, so I need to render the same; below is the sample xml

```
<Item>
<ItemName><![CDATA[Name]]></ItemName>
<ItemValue><![CDATA[請お]]></ItemValue>
</Item>
```

And when I am trying to render this in a simple fo:block I am getting below warning :

> [WARN] FOUserAgent - Glyph "請" (0x8acb) not available in font
> "Helvetica".
>
> [WARN] FOUserAgent - Glyph "お" (0x304a, ohiragana) not available in
> font "Helvetica".

And finally my in my pdf it is coming like '##' so what could be the possible solution for this?

Let me know if we need any further information regarding the same.

My xslt code for rendering the value:

```
 <fo:block font-size="3.4mm">
  <xsl:value-of select="Item/ItemValue"/>
 </fo:block>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache FOP Displaying ### with SimSun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895984/apache-fop-displaying-with-simsun)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure FOP to use a Japanese font.  See, e.g.:

- https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/faq.html#pdf-characters
- https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.8/fonts.html